# Retrieving specific data from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a chat app on android using Firebase Database and Java. Whenever the user is first registered, it stores their username into the database under the nodes `user/UserID/profile/username`. The username is stored using a User class. This is where the username value is stored. However when I try something like

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(UserID).child("profile").child("username").toString();
```

This gives me the path to the username but not the username itself. Does anybody know how to get the value of the username itself?

EDIT: It gives me an error when I run

```
DataSnapshot.child("users").child(mUserID).child("profile").child("username").getValue().toString();
```

Here is what my Firebase database shows under the UserID.

[image: Firebase database profile]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't getting the value properly. You need to attach a listener to you child and get updates. You do that like this:

```
// Get a reference to your user
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/path/to/profile");

// Attach a listener to read the data at your profile reference
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Profile profile = dataSnapshot.getValue(Profile.class);
        System.out.println(profile.getUsername());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```

You can find more information and examples on the Firebase [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data). Keep in mind that you don't make requests to get data from Firebase. You attach listeners to the children and then get the data from the listener. This example assumes that you have a `Profile` model, with a method to get the username. This would return your `Profile` object and would enable you to get whatever data you need off of that object.

Comment: This code is in a ChildEventListener. Should I use a ValueEventListener instead?

Comment: You can use the ChildEventListener too. That gives you some other options like remove, update, add, etc.

Comment: What if I don't use a model class? How would I retrieve the data without it? Or is it necessary that I use it?

Comment: You need to have a model class of some sort. It's good design. Aside from this, you are most likely going to be pulling other data off of this, so you should have some sort of model. Look at your design, and figure out what works best for you. Currently you have a "Profile" but maybe you want more of a User model, that would include name, display name, address, email, ect. You definitely want to have some sort of model, what that looks like is up to you, but you could have it include the data you want now.

Comment: Okay thanks. The only issue I had with a model class is that every time i would try to pull data from it, I would get an error saying that I'm trying to get a null reference to it at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try this you forgot about the getValue() that will return the value not the path    `mDatabase.child("users").child(UserID).child("profile").child("username").getValue().toString();`

Comment: When I try to use the getValue method, Android studio says it cannot resolve the method. Any idea why? Here is my code: String incom_username = mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("profile").child("username").getValue().toString();

Comment: Never mind. I was using the database reference instead of a DataSnapshot. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, it is still giving me an error saying that it cannot convert a null object reference to a string. I will update my question with a picture.

Comment: This won't work. There is no `getValue()` method for the child function. This also won't return a value of any sort.