# Retrieving Object from Firebase

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
Process: com.example.berkbatuhangurhan.pollmanagerapp, PID: 313
              com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.util.List has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead
```

I've searched other questions about my problem but they didn't seem to work. I'm trying to retrieve my `Poll` object from Firebase and I keep getting the message above;
I've tried using Lists, HashMaps, Generic type paramateres but I've had no luck. I'm in a though spot here any help is welcome

```
DatabaseReference ref =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("polls");

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Poll p1=null;
            for(DataSnapshot childSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                p1=childSnapShot.getValue(Poll.class);
            }
            Poll post =dataSnapshot.getValue(Poll.class);

            Toast.makeText(main_activity.this, "A= "+p1.getPollCreator(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

You can find my poll class below:

```
public class Poll  {
public String pollTitle;
public String pollCreatorEmail;
public Date dateCreated;
public List<Question> questions;
public Date deadLine;
public List<Integer> votes;
public int pollPrivacy;
public boolean pendStatus=false;

public Poll(String pollTitle, String pollCreatorEmail, int pollPrivacy,boolean pendStatus){
    this.pollTitle=pollTitle;
    this.pollCreatorEmail=pollCreatorEmail;
    //this.dateCreated=dateCreated;
    //this.questions=questions;
    //this.deadLine=deadLine;
    //this.votes=votes;
    this.pollPrivacy=pollPrivacy;
    this.pendStatus=pendStatus;
    questions=new ArrayList<Question>();
    votes=new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
public Poll(){}

public String getPollTitle(){
    return pollTitle;
}
public void setPollTitle(String newTitle){
    pollTitle=newTitle;
}
public String getPollCreator(){
    return pollCreatorEmail;
}
public void setPollCreator(String pollCreatorEmail){
    this.pollCreatorEmail=pollCreatorEmail;
}
// SKIPPED ATTRIBUTE METHODS
public List<Question> getQuestions(){
    return questions;
}
public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions){
        this.questions=questions;
}
public Date getDeadLine(){
    return deadLine;
}
public void setDeadLine(Date newDeadLine){
    deadLine=newDeadLine;
}
public void sharePoll(){

}
public void addQuestion(Question question){
    questions.add(question);
}
public void deleteQuestion(Question question){
    questions.remove(question);
}
public List<Integer> getVotes(){
    return votes;
}
public void setVotes(Integer index){
    votes.add(index,votes.get(index)+1);
}
public void votePoll(Question question){
    //????????????????????????????
}
public void setPollPrivacy(int privacy){
    pollPrivacy=privacy;
}
public int getPollPrivacy(){
    return pollPrivacy;
}
}
```

My database structure

-Polls
  -PollTitle1
     -pollCreator
     -status
     -Questions
          -1
             -qText
             -qNum
  -PollTitle2

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/GenericTypeIndicator

Comment: That means encase your List declaration in a GenericTypeIndicator

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your database? Also, one of my older questions might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241450/retrieving-specific-data-from-firebase-database

Comment: I’ve tried generic type indicators but didnt work

Comment: can you attach sample database structure

Comment: could you structure your data from firebase

Comment: I cant upload images but I added My structure

Comment: Please add your database structure.